# In spring project, I get 400 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In Spring project, I get 400 error whether the requestparam is wrong on the controller.

Here is my code.

```
@RequestMapping("theater_delTheater.do")
public String theater_updateTheater(@RequestParam int idx){
    theaterService.delTheater(Integer.parseInt(idx));
    return "/insang/test";
}
```

Idx in requestparam is a numeric type and is a movie unique code in a movie theater.

Comment: So, what do you want? What is your problem?

Comment: Show request code (from the frontend), or show us url which you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has no much sense...

According with the [status code definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) the 400 error code means

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Which is exactly what you say in the question

> I get 400 error **whether the requestparam is wrong on the controller.**

That means that when your requestparam is wrong, your method can not resolve the request.

So the solution is very simple: avoid making request with a wrong requestparam (you can do it by verifying the requestparam before the controller make the request).

Answer (score 0):

add @ResponseBody annotation with @ResponseMapping.

```
@RequestMapping("theater_delTheater.do")
@ResponseBody
public String theater_updateTheater(@RequestParam int idx) {
    theaterService.delTheater(Integer.parseInt(idx));
    return "/insang/test";
}
```

Comment: No, @ResponseBody - allow to response with body, e.g. with JSON, but in question there is return view (name of the page)